# Pricing and attachments

Tags: cognito-forms

We are interested in using the free version of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

In what situations will the 1% fee apply while on this plan?

Also, when someone fills out the form and has attachments, can those attachments accompany the reply email on the free plan?

Comment: Please note that this is not Cognito support (although they are very active here and answer a lot of questions). Also, not that this a collection of questions and answers; you should limit yourself to a single question in a question post, so that it has the best chance of getting a definitive answer and people can focus their votes in its merit.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a form under the free plan to take a payment, then Cognito will keep 1% of the payment amount (in addition to Stripe's fee. Stripe is a third party that will process card payments).

Uploads by people submitting a form are possible under the free plan. However, under the free plan Cognito will not email the uploaded file to you (possible when you pay). It will, however, include a link in the email that will let you access the uploaded files in your Cognito account.

So far I've set up a few simple Cognito forms for two different clients, all under the Free plan and found it to be very good.